# How to manage Qt project to test new added features?

Tags: c++, qt

I'd like to manage an "Official" Qt Project and a "Trial" version, this last "born" as copy of the official. In the Trial I test new features, not sure if these will be implemented in the Official.
Thus, Official and Trial live independently from each other, until Trial will become an Official brand new.
Meanwhile I could find a bug in the Official, so I have to correct it, both in Official and in Trial.
How can execute all in the best way possible? Is there a way using Qt to develop a copy of an Official project and, if needed, make correction and add tested features in one or the other using Qt? Or bettere to compare files with external text editor to find differences in C++ header and source files?

Comment: You need a version control system. Look at e.g. git or SVN

Comment: Btw, you might want to pick another word instead of "trial", such as "beta version" or "development version". Trial version in SW industry generally means a version meant for end user to try the software, and is usually limited in some way (can't save, can't have bigger than X size files, will exit after X minutes of use, will stop working X days after installation).

Comment: @hide, you're right; probably "beta" or "development" is better. Anyway, my problem still remain the same and here found some interesting solutions I'll test asap.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your scenario with a version control, e.g. [Git](https://git-scm.com/), and by [using branches](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/using-branches).

Answer (score 0):

As pointed in the comments, your problem is not linked to Qt but to [Version Control systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control).

Fortunately, **Qt has a very good integration of VCS**, and has a [tutorial to help you set it up](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-version-control.html). I suggest you follow this tutorial and practice a little bit. Version control systems are an **essential tool** to work on big projects.

[Git is probably a good start](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-vcs-git.html), it is fairly easy to use, and you can get free online hosting / sharing of your projects through [GitHub](https://github.com/).